# How to make a street-light style torch

Tags: design, castle

I need to light up my streets so the citizens of my castle can get around at night. I'd like to do something like this:

[From Etsy listing](https://www.etsy.com/listing/761079174/fire-torch-wall-torch-medieval-torch):

[image]

[From https://www.pixtastock.com/illustration/58823117](https://www.pixtastock.com/illustration/58823117):

[image]

[image: image 3]

(I guess in some places they call this a 'sconce')

I looked around on Bricklink and the closest I found was [this lantern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=37776&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Lantern&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D#T=C) below. But it looks like it only attaches to a hand, so I can't put it on the wall. 
Any suggestions?

[image: From bricklink]

Comment: Lantern use so called 3.18 mm "bar" connection, which is used by multiple of other parts than minifigure hands too. You could position it upward as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Tree Palm Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2566&idColor=8#T=S&C=8&O=%7B%22color%22:8,%22iconly%22:0%7D) was used as lanterns in old pirate sets, for example 6285

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yea, that works. Thanks.  The instructions can be found at https://lego.brickinstructions.com/pdfdrop/6285_1.pdf  step 25

Comment: you can even put a flame piecein the middle - if you use the short one, prop it up with a few round 1x1s

Answer (score 9):

1989's [Eldorado Fortress](https://brickipedia.fandom.com/wiki/6276_Eldorado_Fortress) from the Pirates universe had torches made from part [3959](https://rebrickable.com/parts/3959/weapon-gun-torch-space-with-grooves/) with a single transparent stud on the "top", with the entire assembly pushed into an Erling brick.

[image: Part 3959]

You can get a similar effect by clipping a [lightsaber hilt piece](https://rebrickable.com/parts/64567/weapon-lightsaber-hilt-with-bottom-ring/) to the wall or putting it onto a post. Just add a suitable flame piece (or simple stud) coming out of one end. For a recent handheld version of this (could be easily adapted to a stationary lamp), see Ninjago set 70671, [Lloyd's Journey](https://brickset.com/sets/70671-1).